# Show contents created by admin on specific profile pages of users in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm working with a job vacancies site with drupal. There's a content type named CV and there are specific profile pages for specific users(I use Profile2 module).
**What I want to do is when admin add a new CV for a specific user, that cv is posted on that user's profile page.**
I can create cv content but can't link to that user's profile page.
I've find possible answers on google and can't find the right one.

Comment: How about adding node reference field to user profile which will reference nodes in CV type?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, you can create a page view that displays nodes of type CV and uses the User ID (from logged in user or URL) as a contextual field, then set the path to something like "user/%/CV".

Comment: Thanks for your info.But what I want is a node type created by administrator for users. So, User ID in contextual field will be admin's ID cuz logged in user when create that node is admin.

Comment: You can use the User ID from the URL instead of the current user. So admin (uid 1) can look at "user/5/CV" and it will display user 5's CV's.